# UITableViewCell/UITextField draw issue when Datasource is larger than row number

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

So, this is driving me nuts...
Everything works great, unless my datasource: an *NSMutableArrray*: **_names** contains more items than there are rows visible in the *UITableView*: **namesTable**.
then all hell breaks loose... cells are overlaying one another, there are empty cells, repeating cells.

here is my setup code.

```
    @interface DetailViewController ()
    {
        NSMutableArray *_names;
    }
```

My viewDidLoad method:

```
    - (void) viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(handleBack:)];

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
        if (!_names)
            _names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
```

and cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellId = @"MyCustomCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
        UITextField *nameTextField;

        if (!cell || refreshCells)
        {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
                                                                  self.view.bounds.origin.y+10,
                                                                  self.view.bounds.size.width-19,
                                                                  26.0)];*/
             nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x+10,
                                                                  self.view.bounds.origin.y+4,
                                                                  self.view.bounds.size.width-19,
                                                                  34.0)];
        }

        nameTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        nameTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        nameTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        nameTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        nameTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        nameTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        nameTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:22.0];
        nameTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        nameTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        nameTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
        nameTextField.delegate = self;
        nameTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        NSString *object = _names[indexPath.row];
        nameTextField.text = [object description];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:nameTextField];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }
```

can anybody, please tell show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: show your code for numberOfRowsInSection. and check if there is no null value in your array. What error you are getting exactly????

Comment: - (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            return _names.count;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subclassing UITableViewCell, and moving most of this code into:

```
@implementation DetailViewCustomCell
@synthesize nameTextField;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        nameTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        nameTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        nameTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        nameTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        nameTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        nameTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:22.0];
        nameTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        nameTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [self.contentView addSubview:nameTextField];
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x+10;
    CGFloat boundsY = contentRect.origin.x+4;
    CGFloat boundsW = contentRect.size.width-19;
    CGRect frame;
    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX ,boundsY, boundsW, 34.0);
    nameTextField.frame = frame;
}
```

and in my view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    DetailViewCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[DetailViewCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSString *object = _names[indexPath.row];
    cell.nameTextField.text = [object description];
    cell.nameTextField.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use XIB to design your cell, instead of writing this much code. Also what is that refreshCells?? Also where are you adding data to your Array??

Better try to design the cell in XIB and IBOutlet it. Then load it in cellForRow...

In your code every time you are adding one textfield to your cell

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:nameTextField];
```

which is not necessary at all..

This could solve your problem.

Comment: I have replaced this line: `[cell.contentView addSubview:nameTextField];` with this: `[cell setAccessoryView:nameTextField];` which fixes the rendering. but when I swipe the cell to delete, the textfield disappears, and only reappears when I "unswipe"?